# How to make use of $(u · \nabla)u = \nabla P, \operatorname{div} u = 0$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, divergence-theorem

I come up a problem when solving the following question:

Let $\boldsymbol{u} = (u_1(x, y), u_2(x, y))$ be a smooth planar vector field and $P = P(x, y)$ be a scalar function in $\Omega$ satisfying
$(u · \nabla)u = \nabla P, \operatorname{div} u = 0$.
Here $(u · \nabla)u$ is understood as $\sum_{k=1}^2
u_k\partial_k \boldsymbol{u}$. Derive the partial differential equation of
$\omega = \partial_2u_1 − \partial_1u_2$ which only involves $\boldsymbol{u}$
and $\nabla ω$ but not involve $P$.

I first write $\omega$ as $\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}-\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}$ and then compute the derivative
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}w &= \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x+
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y\\
&= \left(\dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial y \partial x}
- \dfrac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x^2}\right)
\mathrm{d}x
+\left(
\dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial y^2}
-\dfrac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x \partial y}\right)
\mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}
Then I can not see any relation between $\omega$ and $\boldsymbol{u}$.
I do not know how to make use of the information $(u · \nabla)u = \nabla P, \operatorname{div} u = 0$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $\Omega$ an area on $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: It's a bit stange because I saw $u\cdot\nabla=\text{div}u=0$, then $P(x,y)$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes... that is very strange.

Comment: I only get the identity $\nabla\omega+\nabla(\nabla\times\mathbf{u})=0$.

Comment: Can you give a detailed explanation?

Comment: $\omega=-\nabla\times\mathbf{u}$ and do $\nabla$ on both sides.

Comment: I think that $\nabla (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{u})$ is always $0$. This is even more weird.

Comment: Also, I don't think that $\boldsymbol{u} \cdot \nabla = \operatorname{div}\boldsymbol{u}$ because we can not consider the $\cdot$ here as a vector dot product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector field $\mathbf{u} = (u_1(x,y),u_2(x,y))$  satifies $(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{u} = \nabla P$ which reduces to two component equations

$$\tag{1a}u_1 \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+u_2 \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$$
$$\tag{1b}u_1 \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}+u_2 \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$$

Take the partial derivative of both sides of (1a) with respect to $y$ and the partial derivative of both sides of (1b) with respect to $x$ to obtain

$$\tag{2a}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+ u_1 \frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial y\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}+u_2 \frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial y^2}= \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y\partial x}$$
$$\tag{2b}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}+ u_1 \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}+u_2 \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x\partial y}= \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x\partial y}$$

Subtracting  (2b) from (2a) we get

$$\tag{3}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}\left( \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}\right)+ \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}\left( \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}\right)\\+u_1 \left(\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial y\partial x}- \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x^2}\right)+ u_2 \left(\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial y^2}- \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x\partial y}\right)\\ = \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y\partial x}-\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x\partial y}$$

Assuming $P$, $u_1$, and $u_2$ are twice continuously differentiable, we have equality of mixed second-order partial derivatives by Clairaut's theorem.  Consequently, the RHS of (3) is $0$ and we can rearrange to obtain

$$\tag{4}\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}\right)\left( \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}\right)+u_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}\right)+ u_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}\right) = 0$$

Substituting into (4) with $\displaystyle \omega = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}= \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$ , we get the result

$$\boxed{u_1 \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} + u_2 \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial y} = 0}$$

Comment: In effect, we are deriving this by taking the curl of both sides of $\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla \mathbf{u} = \nabla P$. Using the fact that the curl of a gradient is $0$, i.e., $\nabla \times \nabla P = 0$ we would get $\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla\left(\omega\mathbf{e_z}\right) - (\omega \mathbf{e_z})\cdot \nabla \mathbf{u}  = 0$. The second term vanishes since the components of $\mathbf{u}$ do not depend on $z$.